# Show Activity Indicator(SVProgress HUD) after 3 seconds in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode7, delay, svprogresshud

I am using `SVProgressHUD` as an activity indicator in my project. I don't want to show `HUD` if my data loads faster than 3 seconds, it should show only after this time period. I am not able to delay the loading of `SVProgress` `HUD`.

Answer (score 2):

Use following code :

```
  [self performSelector:@selector(addHUD) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0f];
```

If data loads before 3 sec call

```
 [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(addHUD) object:nil];
```

Also add above line in dealloc method.

Comment: how to write condition for data loads before 3.0 seconds?

Comment: Take time timestamp before starting the data load. Start data loading, inside data loading completion handler compare current time stamp with previous time stamp.

Comment: Same thing will work. Only change will be you have to maintain add member which holds the time stamp before you start data load. Compare time in data load finish delegate method.

Comment: if would be helpful if u could provide some code @arun ammannaya